# How do I add a timestamp to a gridview

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, datetime, datagridview

How do I add a timestamp to a gridview that shows the last time a row was edited? I've been searching Google but haven't found anything helpful yet.

I tried to create a method which will update the time when you edit or add a column. but i dont know how to take it further like parsing it to each and every column.

my table columns

```
    private DataTable GetDataTableFromDataGridview(DataGridView _grid)
    {
      {
            var _oDataTable = new DataTable();
            object[] cellValues = new object[_grid.Columns.Count];
             //clearTable();
            _oDataTable.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
            _oDataTable.Columns.Add("Value", typeof(string));
            _oDataTable.Columns.Add("Font", typeof(string));
            _oDataTable.Columns.Add("DateStamp", typeof(string));
            _oDataTable.Columns.Add("Comment", typeof(string));
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in _grid.Rows)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < row.Cells.Count; i++)
                {
                    cellValues[i] = row.Cells[i].Value;
                }
                _oDataTable.Rows.Add(cellValues.ToArray());
            }
            return _oDataTable;
        }

    }
```

my method

```
    private DateTime _dateTime;
    string _DateTimeFormat = "yyyy/dd/MM HH:mm:ss";
    public void UpdateTheCurrentTime()
    {
        _dateTime = DateTime.Now;
        _dateTime.ToString(_DateTimeFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can handle this on the database side. Since it is a data bound gridview, you just need a datetime field with default value of `NOW()` for MySql. for SQL Server, I believe a persistent computed column with `datetime.now()` would do.

Answer (score 0):

DataGridView.CellValueChanged Event:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellvaluechanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

```
private void MyDataGridView_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)  
{
    DataGridViewRow changedRow = myDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to update record in datatable is by using BeginEdit

```
private void DemonstrateRowBeginEdit()
{
DataTable table = new DataTable("table1");
DataColumn column = new 
    DataColumn("col1",Type.GetType("System.Int32"));
table.RowChanged+=new 
    DataRowChangeEventHandler(Row_Changed);
table.Columns.Add(column);

// Add a UniqueConstraint to the table.
table.Constraints.Add(new UniqueConstraint(column));

// Add five rows.
DataRow newRow;

for(int i = 0;i<5; i++)
{
    // RowChanged event will occur for every addition.
    newRow= table.NewRow();
    newRow[0]= i;
    table.Rows.Add(newRow);
}
// AcceptChanges.
table.AcceptChanges();

// Invoke BeginEdit on each.
Console.WriteLine(
    "\n Begin Edit and print original and proposed values \n");
foreach(DataRow row in table.Rows)
{

    row.BeginEdit();
    row[0]=(int) row[0]+10;
    Console.Write("\table Original \table" + 
        row[0, DataRowVersion.Original]);
    Console.Write("\table Proposed \table" + 
        row[0,DataRowVersion.Proposed] + "\n");
}
Console.WriteLine("\n");
// Accept changes
table.AcceptChanges();
// Change two rows to identical values after invoking BeginEdit.
table.Rows[0].BeginEdit();
table.Rows[1].BeginEdit();
table.Rows[0][0]= 100;
table.Rows[1][0]=100;
try
{
    /* Now invoke EndEdit. This will cause the UniqueConstraint
       to be enforced.*/
    table.Rows[0].EndEdit();
    table.Rows[1].EndEdit();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    // Process exception and return.
    Console.WriteLine("Exception of type {0} occurred.", 
        e.GetType());
}
}

private void Row_Changed(object sender, 
   System.Data.DataRowChangeEventArgs e)
{
 DataTable table = (DataTable)  sender;
 Console.WriteLine("RowChanged " + e.Action.ToString() 
     + "\table" + e.Row.ItemArray[0]);
}
```

Comment: i don't know where to start or how can i apply this to meet my needs