# How to add datestamp to the datagridview

Tags: c#, xml, datetime, datagridview

I have an xml file which the user will load to the datagridview and write to the file. all this it working fine. on the xml i have datestamp column which 
will load the date automatically and it must also update the time when the user 
edited from other cell. i tried many examples yesterday but i didn't come with a working solution or from the question i asked. today i created a class to try to update my column but it is not working

when i debug from CellEndEdit and my class throws an error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." , i cant even step into my class and see where the error it is.

Question : how can i get the time get updated automatically when you edit or write to the file?

my codes

my column for datestamp

```
private DataTable GetDataTableFromDataGridview(DataGridView _grid)
{
    {
        var _oDataTable = new DataTable();
        object[] cellValues = new object[_grid.Columns.Count];
        _oDataTable.Columns.Add("DateStamp", typeof(DateTime));

        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in _grid.Rows)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < row.Cells.Count; i++)
            {
                cellValues[i] = row.Cells[i].Value;
            }

            _oDataTable.Rows.Add(cellValues.ToArray());
        }

        return _oDataTable;
    }
}

private void Gridview_Output_CellEndEdit(object sender,  DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        _UpdateTime.UpdateTimeNow();
    }
}
```

my class

```
namespace Project
{
    class UpdateTime
    {
        public UpdateTime()
        {
        }

        private Regex _dateRegex = new Regex(@"(?<=\[DateStamp\]).*?(?=\[/DateStamp\])");
        public string _DateFormat = "yyyy/dd/MM HH:mm:ss";
        private DateTime _date;
        private XElement _datenodes;

        public string DateStamp
        {
            get
            {
                return _date.ToString(_DateFormat); 
            }
        }

        public void UpdateTimeNow()
        {
            _date = DateTime.Now;
            DateTime _dt;
            this._datenodes.Value = string.Format("[DateStamp]{3}[/DateStamp]",this._date.ToString(_DateFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
            if (DateTime.TryParseExact(_dateRegex.Match(this._datenodes.Value).Value, _DateFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out _dt))
            {
                this._date = _dt;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry but you asked _almost_ same question yesterday. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28741205/how-do-i-add-a-timestamp-to-a-gridview Instead of asking a new question, improve the old one or when you have enough reputation, put a bountry.

Comment: thanks for advice. i will do that next time

Comment: It helps if you format your bloody code to

Comment: @ITForward your error suggest you are not instantiating _UpdateTime correctly, e.g. UpdateTime _UpdateTime = new UpdateTime(); ... where is your declaration for it?

Comment: getting error on this line
 this._datenodes.Value = string.Format("[DateStamp]{3}[/DateStamp]",this._date.ToString(_DateFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));

Comment: @ITForward you haven't initialized _datenodes or a number of things for that matter.

Comment: i did but it is not updating the time on the gridview column

Comment: Where have you initialized `_datenodes`?

Comment: private XElement _datenodes = new XElement() , it shows error and i wrote this  XElement _datenodes = new XElement("Datestamp")

Answer (score 0):

this did the job for me......thanks everyone

```
   private void Gridview_Output_RowLeave(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            if (Gridview_Output.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "ValueOut")
            {
                if (Gridview_Output.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].EditedFormattedValue.ToString().Length > 0)
                {
                    string datetime = DateTime.Now.ToString(_DateFormat);
                    Gridview_Output.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Value = datetime;
                }
            }
```